# "I will say it is better" emphasizing "will"

Tags: tense, spoken-english, will-would

In my shop I am selling a new thing. And a customer asks me about the quality of the new thing.

And I responded by saying:

> I **will** say it is better, since I am selling it. First use then see.

Here I am emphasizing the sentence with the word**will** to show that it is typical of any **seller** to say that **their products are better.**

Is it a natural way to express this?
I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score -1):

The word you emphasize indicates the opposition you have met or expect to meet:

> ***I*** will say it is better. [since you claim it's someone else who says it's better]
>
> I ***will*** say it is better. [since you claim I won't say it is better]
>
> I will say it ***is*** better.
>   I will say it is ***better***. [since you claim it's actually worse]